# Efficiently create derangement of a vector in R

Tags: r, performance, vector, permutation

I'm looking into a way of efficiently creating a derangement (and conversely specific permutations) of a vector in R.
As far as I've seen, there's no base function that does that and also there's not much about it here on SO.

An obvious start is `sample` which creates a permutation of a vector. But I need this permutation to have no fixed points, hence be a derangement of the vector. For a nice explanation of this topic, see [this Cross Validated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187080/probability-that-secret-santa-arrangement-will-result-in-perfect-pairings/187104#187104).

This is my first approach:

```
derangr <- function(x){

  while(TRUE){

    xp <- sample(x)

     if(sum(xp == x) == 0) break

  }

  return(xp)

}
```

So within a `while` loop, I'm checking if there's a fixed point between a vector `x` and a given permutation of `x` called `xp`. If there is none, I break the loop and return the vector.

As the results show, it works fine:

```
> derangr(1:10)
 [1]  4  5  6 10  7  2  1  9  3  8

> derangr(LETTERS)
 [1] "C" "O" "L" "J" "A" "I" "Y" "M" "G" "T" "S" "R" "Z" "V" "N" "K" "D" "Q" "B" "H" "F" "E" "X" "W" "U" "P"
```

So I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing that, potentially with substituting `while` by a vectorization of some kind. I also want to keep an eye on scalability.

Here's the `microbenchmark` for both examples:

```
library(microbenchmark)

> microbenchmark(derangr(1:10),times = 10000)
Unit: microseconds
          expr   min     lq    mean  median      uq      max neval
 derangr(1:10) 8.359 15.492 40.1807 28.3195 49.4435 6866.453 10000

> microbenchmark(derangr(LETTERS),times = 10000)
Unit: microseconds
             expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
 derangr(LETTERS) 24.385 31.123 34.75819 32.4475 34.3225 10200.17 10000
```

The same question applies to the converse, producing permutations with a given number of fixed points `n`:

```
arrangr <- function(x,n){

  while(TRUE){

    xp <- sample(x)

     if(sum(xp == x) == n) break
  }

  return(xp)

}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple occurrences of some values in the vector as you would have in `rep(LETTERS, 2)`? If so, does it matter if the first "A" would be interchanged with the second "A" etc.?

Comment: I'm looking for a general solution, so you're bringing up a good point. My function assumes unique values. If you'd have repeating values, it wouldn't matter if the fist "A" gets interchanged by a second one, as long as no element (or conversely `n`) elements stay at their previous positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have only unique values, you could rearrange an index like and use it for subsetting the input vector in a new order. In this case if you have for example `rep(LETTERS, 2)` the first `A` and the second `A` would be interchangeable. The `derangr()` function proposed in the Q would also rearrange these.

```
derangr2 <- function(x){
  ind <- seq_along(x)
  while(TRUE){
    indp <- sample(ind)
    if(sum(indp == ind) == 0) break

  }
  return(x[indp])
}
```

Some Benchmark results:

```
microbenchmark(derangr(rep(LETTERS, 4)), 
               derangr2(rep(LETTERS, 4)), times = 1000)

# Unit: microseconds
#                      expr   min       lq       mean  median      uq      max neval
#  derangr(rep(LETTERS, 4)) 6.258 113.4895 441.831094 251.724 549.384 5837.143  1000
# derangr2(rep(LETTERS, 4)) 6.542   7.3960  23.173800  12.800  22.755 4645.936  1000
```

However, if you face only unique values, this approach doesn't hold a lot of improvement.

```
microbenchmark(derangr(1:1000), derangr2(1:1000), times = 1000)
# Unit: microseconds
#             expr    min     lq     mean median      uq      max neval
#  derangr(1:1000) 19.341 21.333 61.55154 40.959 78.0775 2770.382  1000
# derangr2(1:1000) 23.608 25.884 72.76647 46.079 84.1930 2674.243  1000
```

Comment: +1 once I read your comment, I had a similar idea. This is definitely an improvement. Just revisiting part of my question, there's no way then to substitute `while` or other loops? If so, I'm considering this a solution. And, shouldn't `derangr2` return `x[indp]`?

Comment: I just experimented with only rearranging the values where `indp == ind`. However, in theory this can create an infinite loop, if only one value fitting this condition is left. ... So no improvement there.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I don't think `derangr3` can execute. You're evaluating `indp` before it's defined.

Comment: I admit I did get excited for a moment until I realized

Comment: I will accept your solution as answer for the time being since it was a key enhancement. However, I was also looking if there's a solution without using a loop.

Comment: I thought about it and did not come to a (even theoretical) solution without the necessity of iterative checks. The only improvement could be by using e.g. C++ (Rcpp) or built in solutions. So long, this might be the only approach possible...

Comment: That was my feeling as well, hence I accepted your solution. Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

The main inefficiency in your present derangement function is that if it finds a fixed point in the permutation it regenerates the *entire permutation* instead of just making some minimal change to try to remove the fixed point.  A faster method is to begin by generating a permutation, then swap fixed points with random elements until there are no more fixed points.  Using this method you only swap two values (at random) each time you find a fixed point, instead of regenerating the entire permutation.

If you want to generalise this to specify the number of fixed points (instead of zero) you can extend the algorithm by first doing a random sample of the fixed points and then using a derangement of the remaining elements with no further fixed points.  This is called a [generalised derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Generalizations), and it is a natural extension of the classical derangement with no fixed points.

You can find an algorithm to produce classical and generalised derangments in the [`derange` function](https://github.com/ben-oneill/utilities/blob/main/R/derange.R).  The linked function is "vectorised" to allow multiple derangements to be generated, and it also has some other bells-and-whistles that would slow down the run-time.  In particular, this function allows you to generate generalised derangement with any possible number of fixed points.  If you are only looking to generate classical derangements (with no fixed points) then ---stripped back to its essentials--- the algorithm would look like this:

```
derange <- function(set) {
  
  #Check input set
  n <- length(set)
  if (n < 2)         stop('Error: Input set must have at least two elements')
  
  #Generate derangement
  PERM  <- sample.int(n, size = n, replace = FALSE)
  FIXED <- sum(PERM == 1:n)
  while (FIXED > 0) {
    i <- which(PERM == 1:n)[1]
    j <- (1:n)[-i][sample.int(n-1, size = 1)]
    SWAP    <- PERM[j]
    PERM[j] <- PERM[i]
    PERM[i] <- SWAP
    FIXED <- sum(PERM == 1:n) }
  set[PERM] }
```

You can check that this function produces a valid derangement of the input set (noting that if there are duplicate elements in the input set then these can be swapped validly and this is not considered to be a "fixed point").  If you want the vectorised functionality you can use the linked version.  Below I conduct a benchmarking test to see how the present function performs compared to the other functions in this post.  Unsurprisingly, the present method is a bit faster.

```
#Benchmarking test
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(derangr(LETTERS), derangr2(LETTERS), derange(LETTERS), times = 10^6)

Unit: microseconds
              expr min  lq     mean median   uq     max neval
  derangr(LETTERS) 4.6 5.9 16.89053   11.1 20.5 58666.6 1e+06
 derangr2(LETTERS) 5.0 6.4 17.12375   11.5 20.7 20171.4 1e+06
  derange(LETTERS) 4.2 5.4 11.74055    9.9 14.0 37522.1 1e+06
```