# Assign a vector element to another element in the same vector that is not itself (Secret Santa algorithm)

Tags: r

I have an office Secret Santa. Each person needs to be assigned someone to buy a gift for. For simplicity, let's refer to these people by letters.

First, I create the vector of people called `peeps`

```
# People
peeps <- letters[1:20]
```

Next, I set the seed for the RNG.

```
# Set RNG seed
set.seed(43)
```

Then, I sample the people and assign a giver to a receiver.

```
# Create data frame of givers and receiver 
data.frame(giver = peeps, receiver = sample(peeps, length(peeps))) 

#    giver receiver
# 1      a        l
# 2      b        h
# 3      c        d
# 4      d        b
# 5      e        e   <-  Problem!!!
# 6      f        j
# 7      g        s
# 8      h        n
# 9      i        g
# 10     j        t
# 11     k        q
# 12     l        f
# 13     m        k
# 14     n        i
# 15     o        a
# 16     p        m
# 17     q        p
# 18     r        c
# 19     s        r
# 20     t        o
```

Notice row #5. `e` has been assigned themselves, which doesn't work. So, this time I loop through the people and I prevent self assignment.

```
# Set RNG seed
set.seed(7)

# Result data frame
res <- data.frame(giver = peeps, receiver = character(length(peeps)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Loop through people
for(i in 1:nrow(res)){
  # Get sample that is not self
  res[i, "receiver"] <- sample(peeps[peeps != res$giver[i]], 1)

  # Remove from vector
  peeps <- peeps[peeps != res[i, "receiver"]]
}
```

This particular case throws the following error.

```
# Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
#   invalid first argument
```

If we look at the resulting data frame you'll see it worked for all except the final person.

```
res

#    giver receiver
# 1      a        k
# 2      b        h
# 3      c        b
# 4      d        s
# 5      e        n
# 6      f        i
# 7      g        m
# 8      h        l
# 9      i        d
# 10     j        q
# 11     k        p
# 12     l        j
# 13     m        r
# 14     n        e
# 15     o        c
# 16     p        o
# 17     q        g
# 18     r        f
# 19     s        a
# 20     t
```

`t` is yet to be assigned a receiver, but the only receiver left is... `t`!

```
# Check which letters are left
peeps

#[1] "t"   <- Same as final letter!!!
```

**Question:** what is an efficient way of assigning a member of `peeps` to another member of `peeps` that is *not* themself?

Comment: Does it have to be random? You could just shift each letter by one, and rotate back from 'z' to 'a'? If randomness is important, just assign the letters to the people at random...

Comment: @user2474226 Yes, it has to be random. Sorry, I should have stated that in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459623/efficiently-create-derangement-of-a-vector-in-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be talking about [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) (fixed-point free permutations). By a classic probability result, the probability that a randomly chosen permutation is a derangement is essentially 1/e, independent of the size of the set being sampled from. Just use a naive hit-and-miss approach. Generate random permutations using sample() until you get one that works. On average, roughly 3 trials should yield a success.

```
derangement <- function(v){
  while(TRUE){
    p <- sample(v)
    if(all(p != v)) return(p)
  }
}

peeps <- letters[1:20]
set.seed(43)
print(derangement(peeps))
```

Output:

```
[1] "j" "r" "b" "l" "f" "i" "t" "g" "c" "n" "d" "s" "p" "o" "q"
[16] "k" "a" "e" "h" "m"
```

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer. Trail-and-error sounds like a surprisingly efficient solution. Out of curiosity, though: is there an alternative?

Comment: @Lyngbakr I don't know of one off-hand. As you have discovered, it is tricky to do with a series of random choices since earlier choices can rule out feasible choices later on. Even if you find a solution to that problem, it might be hard to prove that the resulting derangement is chosen uniformly from the set of all derangments. An advantage of the hit-and-miss approach is that it samples uniformly.

Answer (score 4):

You could just shuffle them and then pair them off with the next one...

```
peeps <- letters[1:20]
giver <- sample(peeps)        #random order
receiver <- giver[c(2:length(giver), 1)]

df <- data.frame(giver, receiver)
df <- df[order(df$giver), ]   #restore original order

df
   giver receiver
19     a        o
16     b        t
8      c        f
11     d        i
10     e        d
9      f        e
7      g        c
15     h        b
12     i        k
1      j        m
13     k        s
4      l        r
2      m        p
18     n        a
20     o        j
3      p        l
6      q        g
5      r        q
14     s        h
17     t        n
```

Comment: That's a great solution!