# sample from a vector to get a particular pattern

Tags: r, vector, sample

I have a vector **a= c (1, 2, 3)**

Can I get a procedure to use to arrange the vector to get either

**b=c (3, 1, 2)** or **b=c (2, 3, 1)**

Using   **sample (a,3,replace=FALSE)** gives me (1,2,3),(1,3,2), etc. sometimes which are results I don’t want to have.

Answer (score 0):

If you want derangements (permutations without fixed points) then you can look up:

[Efficiently create derangement of a vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459623/efficiently-create-derangement-of-a-vector-in-r)

and read:

[https://www.cs.upc.edu/~conrado/research/talks/analco08.pdf](https://www.cs.upc.edu/%7Econrado/research/talks/analco08.pdf)

Here is mine code based on link:

```
nDerangment <- function(n){
  
  if(n <= 1) return(0)
  if(n == 2) return(1)
  (n - 1) * (nDerangment(n - 1) + nDerangment(n - 2))
}

randomDerangement <- function(n){
  
  if(n == 1) return (n)
  
  p <- seq_len(n)
  mark <- rep(FALSE, n)
  
  i <- u <- n
  while(u >= 2){
    
    if(!mark[i]){
      
      repeat{
        j <- sample(i-1, 1)
        if(!mark[j]) 
          break()
      }
    
      temp <- p[i]
      p[i] <- p[j]
      p[j] <- temp
    
      prob <- runif(n = 1, 0 , 1)
      if(prob < (u-1) * nDerangment(u-2) / nDerangment(u)){
        mark[j] <- TRUE
        u <- u - 1
      }
      
      u <- u - 1
    }
    
    i <- i-1
  }
  
  p
}
```

Beacuse I count number of derangements recursively this is good only for generating derangement with reasonable small `n`. Of course similar as for fibonacci numbers much better function for calculating derangements would be:

```
nDerangment <- function(n){
  
  if(n <= 1) return(0)
  if(n == 2) return(1)
  
  d_minus_two <- 0
  d_minus_one <- 1
  
  i <- 3
  while(i <= n){
    
    next_d <- (i - 1) * d_minus_one + d_minus_two
    d_minus_two <- d_minus_one
    d_minus_one <- next_d
    
    i <- i + 1
  }
  
  next_d
}
```

Note that you can also write function for calculating number in `if` statement more efficiently by storing number of derangments in global sequance:

```
max_d <- 30
derangements <- vector("integer", max_d)
derangements[[1]] <- 0
derangements[[2]] <- 1
cur_index <- 2

my_fun <- function(n){
  
  if(n > max_d){
    new_vector <- vector("integer", 2*max_d)
    new_vector[seq_len(max_d)] <- derangements
    derangements <<- new_vector
    max_d <<- 2*max_d
  }
  
  if(n <= cur_index) return(derangements[[n]])
  
  for(i in (cur_index+1):n)
    derangements[[i]] <<- i * derangements[[i-1]] + derangements[[i-2]]
  
  
  derangements[[n]]
}
```